# Crypt and send hidden communication between client and server

Tags: php, winforms, encryption, 3des

I have an application winform client written in C# and a Server application written in php.

I need to validate an operation that the client does at the server.

When the client sends this validation it sends to the server some information like LicenseID , Info Points , and other info that I dont want to be spoofed.  I want to prevent fake calls to the server.

The first solution that I used was 3DES to prevent anyone from seeing the clear data that I send via GET and POST methods to the php webserver.

The problem now is that some information like LicenseID and others are always the same.

So even if I encrypt them in 3DES, for each call those encrypted words are always the same and could be easily spoofed.

I want to know if it's possible to send the data, so that they look different in each GET and POST method and I can decrypt in webserver.

What can I change to make each call different from each other while providing the same data?

Update: I forgot to say that I can't use SSL.

Comment: Add some random size random characters to the begining of the encoded stream. You could read the size in other size and skip the random chars.

Comment: This should be an idea. If i dont find any better solution i will use this. Thanks

Comment: @PreferenceBean, Not everyone writes perfect English, or know how to write perfect English but they at least try! To point out grammar and spelling errors and saying that a non native English is disrespectful, THAT is disrespectful! Please write me a message in Swedish and we will se how that goes! :)

Comment: @MaxKielland: If I were to write you a message in Swedish I would put in the 30 seconds' effort it requires to find out how words are capitalised in Swedish. Any less _would_ be disrespectful. I think it's pretty unlikely that the OP was taught to spell "I" like "i" - it was more likely to be lazy "internet speak".

Comment: @PreferenceBean In many countries they are not even taught English in school. In countries where they do, they often don't get the chance to practise because everything is in their native language (including English/American movies). On top of that, many spell checking services (Google included) are just wrong. Just assuming people are lazy because they don't speak your language is kind of arrogant.

Comment: @MaxKielland: Which spell checking services think that "I" is spelt "i"? I really don't think I'm being "arrogant" at all. Honestly, tell me: which educational services teach people to write "i" instead of "I"? Which spell check doesn't catch and correct that? And what non-lazy person doesn't make an extra effort to use a spell check when posting in a language that they _know_ isn't their native language? Modern browsers have a spell check _built-in_. I think it's _highly_ unlikely to be a learning problem, and that you're being really quite rude by calling me names over it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could use a random salt on each information based on some key like the current date, or a pseudo-random salt using the same key in the client and the server. Then you could crypt it all with 3des.

You should also use https after crypting the info. Get an SSL certificate for that.

Comment: Is there a function for separate the salt from the real data? If i add current time to data how can i decrypt in webserver and understand which is time and information? I never seen this salt method in action.

Comment: Well, you will ADD the salt to the end of the string. I thougth about current date since it is changing progressively. But imagine that: You have - LICENCEID + DATE -> HASH -> send HASH -> decode -> LICENSEID + DATE -> REMOVE DATE -> LICENSE ID... Simply compare the date at the end of the string and remove it.

Answer (score 1):

SSL enable your php server.  This will prevent the information getting out to those who may be listening on the wire.  It sounds like this may solve most of your issues.

Comment: I have problem to enable SSL on my webserver cause webhost has problem. I forgot to tell you, sorry. I would resolve without SSL.